# How to highlight rulerformat

Tags: vim, highlight, rc

I want **hi**ghlight the **rulerformat** in my `.vimrc`.

I have

```
set ruler
set rulerformat=%55(%{strftime('%a\ %b\ %e\ %I:%M\ %p')}\ %5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %P%)
```

I have subsequently tried all of the following:

```
hi rulerformat ctermbg=1
hi rulerformat ctermbg=red
hi Group1 ctermbg=red "if you modify the rulerformat slightly you can try to access group 1
```

I don't necessarily want it to be red, but I thought that would stand out the most; anyway, I just cannot get it to work, and I didn't really find anything online (a somewhat unintensive search yielded nothing much). So, how does one **hi**ghlight the **rulerformat**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- edit --

I think I completely missed the point of your question.

What you seem to want is not a way to highlight the value of `'rulerformat'` in your `vimrc` (as your repeated emphasis on **rulerformat**, your title and your introductory sentence imply) but your actual `ruler`, at the bottom of the window.

This is easy to achieve if you follow the instructions at `:help 'statusline'`:

```
hi User1 ctermfg=1 guifg=#80000
set ruler
:set rulerformat=%55(%1*%{strftime('%a\ %b\ %e\ %I:%M\ %p')}\ %5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %P%)%*
```

But you would already have a solution if you cared to read:

```
:help 'ruler'
:help 'rulerformat'
:help 'statusline'
:help hl-User1
```

-- endedit --

The value of `'rulerformat'` is highlighted by default but not as a whole: each character is highlighted individually according to the rules defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim`.

If you want to highlight the whole value with a single color, you will need to add your own rule to your `vimrc`:

```
hi RulerFormat ctermbg=1
augroup RulerFormat
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter vimrc call matchadd('RulerFormat', 'rulerformat=\zs.\+', -1)
augroup END
```

Comment: Well, thanks. That is pretty crazy vimming for me. Also, it doesn't seem to work for me. I don't need it as I am just curious about it, but I am pretty sure it doesn't work in my vim. I have `set t_Co=256` with *solarized* in linux, but I don't think any of that would matter, right?

Comment: Well, I tried it before submitting my answer and it worked but… not anymore. Weird.

Comment: If it helps I tried making things lower case and upper case (for RulerFormat vs rulerformat) and nothing seemed to do the trick. Also, I found a better way of doing what I want (using `:set laststatus=2` `:set statusline="blablabla"`. It would still be cool to figure out this vimscript stuff.

Comment: Using `statusline` is probably the way to go.  It replaces `ruler` completely.  Highlighting `statusline` is rather weird because of the way redraws work in Vim.  Plugin such as [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) or [airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) can take care of these kind of details, but if you insist on doing it on your own, there are a few success stories around. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura :) cheers; I don't really have time, but it would be a fun small project in the future.jkkkk <- vim... I tried to go up and right. haha. I do that too much. (I just hit escape, too.)

Comment: @romainl I accepted, but it still doesn't quite work. If you have time, could you perhaps update it, if you know how or perhaps add a comment saying that it doesn't quite work. Thanks; I've been looking up vim for a while, and you pop up a lot. Keep up the good work. Thanks

Comment: Is it your question that is not clear or me who didn't understand it? Do you want to highlight the value of the `'rulerformat'` option in your `vimrc` or do you want your *ruler* to be highlighted? My answer is an attempt to address the former.

Comment: I did read rulerformat help. It doesn't explain User1 from what I recall. You did address my original and apparently confusing inquiry.:q

Comment: In `:h 'ruler'` you have a pointer to `:h 'rulerformat'` where you have a pointer to `:h 'statusline'` which tells you how to use highlighting and points you toward `:h User1` for further info on "user" highlight groups 1 to 9. Also I second Sato's comment on `'statusline'`.